# import dask_geopandas resulted "cannot import name '_nonempty_index' from 'dask.dataframe.utils' "

Tags: pandas, dask, geopandas

while attempting to import dask_geopandas i encountered errow messages as following:

> > > import dask_geopandas
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\dask_geopandas_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
> > > from . import backends
> > > File "C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\dask_geopandas\backends.py", line 4, in 
> > > from dask.dataframe.utils import (
> > > ImportError: cannot import name '_nonempty_index' from 'dask.dataframe.utils' (C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\utils.py)

what can I do to fix it? thank you.

Comment: First, try upgrading your version of dask-geopandas. If it still fails, please raise an issue on dadk_geopandas - apparently this name has moved from `dask.dataframe.utils` to `dask.dataframe.backends`. The initial underscore suggests it was not meant for use by other packages.

Comment: people with similar issues can install directly from source : pip install git+https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas.git     , as recommended by https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas/issues/86#issuecomment-890059930